# Detecting change in state for Ember object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember-Data and one of my properties is a dictionary data structure. I'd like any update to this dictionary to be converted into an action which sets the parent Model into a "dirty" state.

So here's the config:

#### Model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    // standard types
    foo: DS.attr('string'),
    bar: DS.attr('number'),
    baz: DS.attr('boolean'),
    // dictionary (aka, flexible set of name value pairs)
    dictionary: DS.attr('object')
});
```

#### Transform

```
export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return Ember.Object.create(serialized);
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }  
});
```

This works and let's assume for a moment that the "dictionary" property is defined as:

```
{
    one: { prop1: foo, prop2: bar, prop3: baz },
    two: 2,
    three: "howdy",
    many: [{},{},{}]
}
```

This means that an Ember Object has four properties. These properties can be a string, a number, an array, or an object. What I'd like is to have some way of identifying any changes to this underlying basket of attributes so I can propagate that to the Model and have it adjust its state to "dirty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR - [Working JS Bin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/baxama/1/edit?html,js,output)

In order to accomplish this you have to do the following:
1. Deserialize the raw object and all its nested deep properties to Ember Objects so they could be Observable
2. Add observers to your model for all existing keys dynamically on every change of the raw object reference, because it can change its content and scheme.
3. Remove these dynamic observers on every raw object reference change and assign the new ones 
4. All dynamic properties changes will set timestamp property so that controllers could listen to it

This is a "Deep" transform I wrote in order to accomplish (1):

```js
// app/transforms/deep.js

export
default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserializeRecursively: function(toTraverse) {
    var hash;
    if (Ember.isArray(toTraverse)) {
      return Ember.A(toTraverse.map(function(item) {
        return this.deserializeRecursively(item);
      }, this));
    } else if (!Ember.$.isPlainObject(toTraverse)) {
      return toTraverse;
    } else {
      hash = this.generatePlainObject(Ember.keys(toTraverse), Ember.keys(toTraverse).map(function(key) {
        return this.deserializeRecursively(Ember.get(toTraverse, key));
      }, this));
      return Ember.Object.create(hash);
    }
  },
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return this.deserializeRecursively(serialized);
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  },
  generatePlainObject: function(keys, values) {
    var ret = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
      ret[key] = values[i];
    });
    return ret;
  }
});
```

This is a mixin for Models with deep raw objects which accomplish (2) & (3) & (4)

```js
// app/mixins/dynamic-observable.js

export
default Ember.Mixin.create({
  propertiesToAnalyze: [],
  registerRecursively: function(toTraverse, path, propsToObserve) {
    if (Ember.isArray(toTraverse)) {
      propsToObserve.addObject(path + '.@each');
      if (toTraverse.length > 0) {
        this.registerRecursively(toTraverse[0], path + '.@each', propsToObserve);
      }
    } else if (!(toTraverse instanceof Ember.Object)) {
      propsToObserve.addObject(path);
    } else {
      Ember.keys(toTraverse).forEach(function(propertyName) {
        this.registerRecursively(Ember.get(toTraverse, propertyName), path + '.' + propertyName, propsToObserve);
      }, this);
    }
  },
  addDynamicObserver: function(propertyNameToAnalyze) {
    var propertyToAnalyze = this.get(propertyNameToAnalyze),
      propsToObserve = Ember.A([]),
      currentDynamicProps = this.get('currentDynamicProps'),
      propsToRemove = currentDynamicProps.filter(function(prop) {
        return new RegExp('^' + prop + '.').test(prop);
      });
    propsToRemove.forEach(function(prop) {
      Ember.removeObserver(prop, this, dynamicPropertiesObserver)
    }, this);
    currentDynamicProps.removeObjects(propsToRemove);
    this.registerRecursively(propertyToAnalyze, propertyNameToAnalyze, propsToObserve);
    propsToObserve.forEach(function(prop) {
      Ember.addObserver(this, prop, this, 'dynamicPropertiesObserver');
    }, this);
    currentDynamicProps.addObjects(propsToObserve);
  },
  dynamicPropertiesObserver: function(sender, key, value, rev) {
    this.set('dynamicPropertyTimestamp', new Date().getTime())
  },
  addDynamicObservers: function() {
    this.get('propertiesToAnalyze').forEach(this.addDynamicObserver, this);
  },
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('propertiesToAnalyze').forEach(function(prop) {
      Ember.addObserver(this, prop, this, Ember.run.bind(this, this.addDynamicObserver, prop));
    }, this);
  },
  dynamicPropertyTimestamp: null,
  currentDynamicProps: Ember.A([])
});
```

This is how you use the mixin on a model:

```js
// app/models/some-object.js

import DynamicObservable from 'app/mixins/dynamic-observable';
export
default DS.Model.extend(DynamicObservable, {
  dictionary: DS.attr('deep'),
  propertiesToAnalyze: ['dictionary']
});
```

Finally, this is an array controller which its model is an array of `some-object` models

```js
export
default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  message: '',
  observeDictionaries: function() {
    this.set('message', 'A dictionary has been changed. change time: ' + new Date().getTime());
  }.observes('@each.dynamicPropertyTimestamp')
});
```

Comment: This looks great! One thing I don't know enough about is initialisers ... i notice that your JSBin doesn't seem to depend on them but the code above does. Can you explain?

Comment: That is the way to define custom transform for ember-cli. If you are not using ember-cli you should define the transform the same way I did in the js bin example.

Comment: Oh, I am using ember-cli. What then is the difference between a Transform and a "custom transform" that uses an initializer? For the transforms I've done I just use the `ember g transform deep` scaffolding.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I totally forgot about it

Comment: Code example was edited, so the transform itself is an es6 module